# Pygame sprite invalid rectstyle object

Tags: python, pygame, sprite, python-3.4, rect

I have a classic snake game, Im trying to make the snake bigger, so I started to use printing rects to screen instead of pixels. I tried these codes for that(Im not going to write whole code because it may confused):

```
class Worm(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, surface,seg_width,seg_height):
        self.surface = surface #this is ==> screen=pygame.display.set_mode((w, h))
        self.x = surface.get_width() / 2
        self.y = surface.get_height() / 2
        self.length = 1
        self.grow_to = 50
        self.vx = 0
        self.vy = -seg_width
        self.body = []
        self.crashed = False
        self.color = 255, 255, 0
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(self.x,self.y,seg_width,seg_height)
        self.segment = pygame.Rect(0,0,seg_width,seg_height)
   def move(self):
    """ Move the worm. """
    self.x += self.vx
    self.y += self.vy
    self.rect.topleft = self.x, self.y
    if (self.x, self.y) in self.body:
        self.crashed = True

    self.body.insert(0, (self.x, self.y))   #Func of moving the snake
    new_segment = self.segment.copy() 
    self.body.insert(0, new_segment.move(self.x, self.y)) 
    if len(self.body) > self.length:
        self.body.pop()

    def draw(self):
    for SEGMENT in self.body:    #Drawing the snake
        self.surface.fill((255,255,255), SEGMENT) #This is where I got error <-----
```

My codes are working perfectly if I use pixels, but I want a bigger snake (not longer, I mean thicker) so I thought I can use rects, I tried this, but It gives me;

```
self.surface.fill((255,255,255), SEGMENT) 
ValueError: invalid rectstyle object
```

SEGMENT is actually a tuple of coordinates, why I got this error then?
Also after I press f5, I see this screen first, so basically my theory is working but its a weird output, one rect is smaller than other? **Why?** That "0" is scoreboard, I didnt wrote whole code as I said.

[image]

I just don't understand why, what can I do for fixing it?

I want to say this again because it may confuse too, that *surface* argument is actually representing `screen = pygame.display.set_mode((w, h))` this, where `w = widht` and `h = height`.

This is with pixels, so I want a thicker snake, builded by rects not pixels.

[image]
[image]

> **Edit:** From *nbro*'s answer, I change this one

```
self.body.insert(0, (self.x, self.y,self.x, self.y))
```

So it is a tuple with 4 elements now, but output is very strange..
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's easy to debug your code with a simple `print` somewhere. I have just put a `print` under:

```
def draw(self):
    for SEGMENT in self.body:
        print(SEGMENT)
        self.surface.fill((255,255,255), SEGMENT) #This is where I got error <-----
```

and I immediately discovered your problem. `SEGMENT` has to be a rectangle based shape, which means that you have to specify `x`, `y`, `width` and `height`, but, at certain point, `SEGMENT` assumes a `tuple` value composed of 2 elements, which is not correct, it has to be a tuple of 4 elements!

Specifically the output when I get the error is this:

```
<rect(320, 210, 30, 30)>
<rect(320, 180, 30, 30)>
(320.0, 180.0)
```

Now I think you can try to see why it assumes that third tuple of 2 elements even without my help.